# jquery: Get full css property set as string from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

How to get the full css property set as string from an element with jQuery or JavaScript?

```
var x = $('myelement').css().toString();
```

Comment: @undefined: I don't need a css object, i need css as string...

Comment: Sorry, but have you read what I wrote??